# On certain Android devices I get "aN:aN" instead of the time

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, mobile

I have an LWC cmp used in a community page and that is supposed to display some time Slots! It works fine on devices like Iphone, Ipad, Xiaomi Mi 9T when it comes to the mobile version! But It doesn't work well with these 4 devices ( Pixel 3, Android 11, Xiaomi Poco F2, Android 11, Samsung Galaxy s7, Android 8.0.0, Samsung Galaxy a70, Android 10)

to display the time I used this:

```
<time class="time-slot-item"  onclick={handleSelectedElement} data-value={idx}>
     {timeSlot.startTimeFormat} - {timeSlot.endTimeFormat}
</time>
```

PS : I checked the backend and as expected it works fine !

Any ideas where would be the issue !?
Any help would be appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://caniuse.com/?search=time, I can understand why the Samsung ones would have an issue (assuming they're using the Samsung browser). Doesn't make sense for the Pixel though...

Answer (score 0):

An Update about this question : The solution I implemented was to replace the `<time>` tag by a `<div>` tag and worked like a charm, and I could find it due to David's reply with this link of ressources : [https://caniuse.com/?search=tim](https://caniuse.com/?search=time)e